# Store a result in a .txt or .csv format using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to store a result (which is in an array) in a .txt or .csv format using jupyter notebook so that i don't need to run the code again and use the result directly. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `numpy` array, you can use [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html):

```
import numpy as np

#generating a test array
array = np.random.random((10,4))

#saving the array as a tab separated text file
np.savetxt('test.txt',array,delimiter='\t')

#saving the array as a csv file
np.savetxt('test.csv',array,delimiter=',')
```

Comment: added an answer if it helps please checkmark and upvote it.

Comment: Please accept/checkmark and upvoting on the left of answer if it helps you.